# Why is my database making app force close but works fine after I clear data?

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite

If I clear my data for my app then run it, it works fine. If I reopen or rerun my app it will force close and Throw a `java.lang.NullPointerException`? The errors are in this section of code

```
private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DB_TBL + " (" +
                KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + 
                KEY_LEVEL + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " + 
                KEY_HEALTH + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_CRIT + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_CRIT_RANGE + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_CRIT_INC + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_HIT_RANGE + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_HIT_INC + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_CHAR_IMG + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_TOTAL_XP + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_XP + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_XP_NEEDED + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_COINS + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " + 
                KEY_SMALL_POTS + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_LARGE_POTS + " INTEGER NOT NULL)"
            );

        values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME, "User1");
        values.put( KEY_LEVEL, 1);
        values.put(KEY_HEALTH, 10);
        values.put(KEY_CRIT, 5);
        values.put(KEY_CRIT_RANGE, 2);
        values.put(KEY_CRIT_INC, 2);
        values.put(KEY_HIT_RANGE, 2);
        values.put(KEY_HIT_INC, 0);
        values.put(KEY_TOTAL_XP, 0);
        values.put(KEY_XP, 0);
        values.put(KEY_XP_NEEDED, 5);
        values.put(KEY_COINS, 5);
        values.put(KEY_SMALL_POTS, 0);
        values.put(KEY_LARGE_POTS, 0);
        values.put(KEY_CHAR_IMG, 1);
        db.insert(DB_TBL,  null, values);

    }
```

The `java.lang.NullPointerException` points to this

```
  public int getLevel() {
    open();
    int level = values.getAsInteger(KEY_LEVEL);
    close();
    return level;
}
```

This is my Stack Trace

```
01-04 14:45:45.694: W/dalvikvm(20858): threadid=9: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001e578)
01-04 14:45:45.694: E/AndroidRuntime(20858): FATAL EXCEPTION: UpdateThread
01-04 14:45:45.694: E/AndroidRuntime(20858): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-04 14:45:45.694: E/AndroidRuntime(20858):    at com.tanukiproductions.battleforchristmas.SQLiteTable.getLevel(SQLiteTable.java:110)
01-04 14:45:45.694: E/AndroidRuntime(20858):    at com.tanukiproductions.battleforchristmas.Profile.<init>(Profile.java:57)
01-04 14:45:45.694: E/AndroidRuntime(20858):    at com.tanukiproductions.battleforchristmas.MainMenuScene.onMenuItemClicked(MainMenuScene.java:37)
```

This is the `open()` and `close()`

```
public static void open() throws SQLException{
    ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}

public static void close() throws SQLException{
    ourHelper.close();
}
```

Comment: Values isn't initialized for some reason, is it a global variable? What happens in the open and close functions? Are they querying the db?

Comment: values id initialized and I can link the open and close

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `onCreate()` is not called when you create a new DbHelper object after running your app at least once, `values` is null.

If you want to pull this data from your table use [`SQLiteDatabase#query()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5b%5d,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5b%5d,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

```
public int getLevel() {
    int level = -1;
    open();

    Cursor cursor = ourDatabase.query(DB_TBL, new String[] {KEY_LEVEL}, null, null, null, null, null);
    if(cursor.moveToFirst())
        level = cursor.getInt(0); // get the first column from your Select statement, i.e. KEY_LEVEL

    cursor.close();
    close();
    return level;
}
```

But this only returns the first "level" found, use the `_id` parameter to select a particular row.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm kind of new at databases. How would I use this method?

Comment: You need to parse your basic SELECT statement into the various clauses. The `query()` call above is the equivalent to `SELECT key_level FROM table;`.

Comment: No trouble. Put LogCat statements in your DbHelper methods, like `onCreate()` and `onUpgrade()` to help you visualize when these various methods are run (and more importantly when they are _not_.)

Comment: One more question since `values` is `null` how could i rewrite          `values.put(KEY_XP, XP);
  values.put(KEY_TOTAL_XP, totalXp);
  ourDatabase.update(DB_TBL, values, null, null);`

Comment: Since you are just putting data _into_ `values`, not trying to read data _from_ it, create a new `values` object. (So add `values = new ContentValues()`)

Comment: Awesome thanks now I understand the difference between `ContentValues` and `Cursor`